# Can't get second level of a CSS/html dropdown menu to work

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to add a second level to a dropdown menu using CSS.  Its an immutable
requirement that when hovering over the trigger text that the menu complex 
displays, and the first level (Options >>>, menu X) looks fine, but no matter
what I do, I can't prevent the options level (option X, etc), from displaying
at the top level.  I need these options to display to the side on hover over Options >>>.  I haven't included the second level CSS code cause not one of 
all the things I've tried have come close to working, so I'm not sure what 
to even include.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<style type="text/css">

.menu {
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

.menu * {
    display:block; 
    padding:0; margin:0;
}

.menu ul {
    display:none;
}

.menu:hover ul {
    display:block;  
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:100%;
    border:solid 1px black;
    background: white;
    }

    .menu li a {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: arial, sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding:15px 0px 15px 15px;   
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    text-decoration: none;   
}

.menu a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}


</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class='menu'>
        <span class='triggerclass' style='width:150px'>Trigger</span>   
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Options &nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&gt;&gt;</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the arrangement or appearance you desire.  Home | Options | Menu 1 | 2 |3 | 4 should be a horizontal navigation?  Then when hovering over Options >>> the sub-menu appears beneath the primary nav bar with Option 1-3 stacked vertically?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/bd1eftst/

Comment: That seems about right from my interpretation @hungerstar - you should make it an answer.

Comment: @ hungerstar, absolutely.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is a flyout menu. There are plenty of tutorials on the web to do this with just CSS.

Here's the CSS I added to your code in the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd1eftst/) I linked to in the comment below your question.

**CSS**

```
.menu li {
    position: relative;
}
.menu:hover li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 0;
}
```

The reason the code you posted doesn't work is for a few key reasons and those are what make a CSS flyout menu work.

First, the `li` containing a submenu should have `position: relative` set as that submenu will use `position: absolute`. This allows you to position the submenu based on the `li`'s position in the document when you use absolute positioning.

Once this is done, position the submenu based on the parent `li`. Using `top: 0; left: 0;` for the submenu would place it's upper left hand corner under that of the upper left hand corner of the parent `li`. While this aligns the top of the submenu with the top of the parent `li` it hides the submen. To fix this you move the submenu left the width of the parent `li`, `left: 150px`.

Second, you need to display the submenu when an `li` containing a menu is hovered with `li:hover ul`.

That's about it.

This can be a little confusing if you are not used to using the [CSS position property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

Hope this helps!

****EDIT****

OP asked how to contain the submenu display to only a single submenu so that a submenu(s) of a submenu (and so on) are not displayed.  Simple, use the [Child Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

**CSS**

```
.menu:hover li:hover > ul
```

See the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd1eftst/1/).

Comment: I tried to add a third layer to this but it always displays when you hover over its parent's parent, although in the correct position.  How would you modify the CSS for that to work?

Comment: This has to do with how the second rule I added is constructed, `.menu:hover li:hover ul`. That rule says, "if you're hovering an `li` while hovering `.menu` then display ANY `ul` THAT IS A CHILD/DESCENDANT of the currently hovered `li`." We need to make the rule more specific so it will only display the immediate descendant `ul` of the hovered `li`. You do that with the Child Selector `>` which is the greater than symbol. Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bd1eftst/1/.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code or knowing what exactly isn't working would be very helpful.

Forewarning: this code looks pretty complex and there are some moving parts, but once you have it in place, adding new menus, submenus and "super" submenus is a snap - all you have to do is add an unordered list and assign the appropriate classes.  Really easy.  The complex part is the jQuery rememebring which supersubmenu is currently showing and to manage what happens when people move their mouse all over the place.

That said, try this idea:  Display the first list element in each menu "section", and set all others, underneath it, to display:none.  Give them specific classes, and set hover of top element to display other list elements.  If you need a "third" layer, create a SEPARATE list that is completely hidden.  Add a SEPARATE class to the "submenu" item that will trigger the display of the third layer, then add an event handler for the second layer's hover that will display the third.  Difficult to explain, but here's an example:

HTML:

```
<div style="display:table-cell; margin:auto; border:none;" runat="server" id="divMenu">
    <ul class="MainMenu">
        <li class="MainMenu NoSuperSub">ES</li>
        <li class="MainMenu SubMenu Link NoSuperSub" data-url="WebPage.aspx" style="display:none;">Go To A Page</li>
        <li class="MainMenu SubMenu SubWithSub" data-menu="AnotherMenu" style="display:none;">Open Another Menu</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<ul class="MainMenu SuperSubMenu" id="AnotherMenu" style="display:none; margin:auto; border:none;">
    <li class="MainMenu SubMenu Link SuperSubMenu" data-url="WebPage.aspx" style="display:none;">Another WebPage</li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
 //Global Variables

        var SuperSubMenuName;
        var CurrentMenu;
        var TopPosition;
        var LeftPosition;
        var ViewingSuperSubMenu = false;
        var SetTimeOutFunction;

        //Event Handlers

        $("li.MainMenu").mouseover(function (e) {
            $(this).css("display", "inline-block");
            $(this).siblings().css("display", "inline-block");
        });

        $("ul.MainMenu").mouseout(function (e) {
            $(this).children("li").each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop("class").toString().indexOf("SubMenu") >= 0)
                    $(this).css("display", "none");
            });
        });

        $(".Link").click(function (e) {
            $("#PostBackURL").val($(this).data("url"));
            $("#PostBackValue").val("MenuSelection");
            $("#aspnetForm").submit();
        });

        $("li.SubWithSub").mouseover(function (e) {
            HideSuperSubMenu();
            CurrentMenu = $(this).parent("ul").parent("div");
            position = getPosition(this);
            TopPosition = position.y - 108 ;
            LeftPosition = position.x + 117;
            SuperSubMenuName = "#" + $(this).data("menu");
            ShowSuperSubMenu();
            ViewingSuperSubMenu = false;
            clearTimeout(SetTimeOutFunction);
            SetTimeOutFunction = setTimeout(HideSuperSubMenuIfNotViewing, 1000);
        });

        $("ul.SuperSubMenu").mouseover(function (e) {
            CurrentMenu.children("ul").children("li").each(function () {
                $(this).css("display", "inline-block");
            });
            ViewingSuperSubMenu = true;
        });

        $("ul.SuperSubMenu").mouseout(function (e) {
            CurrentMenu.children("ul").children("li").each(function () {
                if ($(this).prop("class").toString().indexOf("SubMenu") >= 0)
                    $(this).css("display", "none");
            });
            ViewingSuperSubMenu = false;
        });

        $("li.NoSuperSub").mouseover(function (e) {
            HideSuperSubMenu();
        });

        //Functions

        function ShowSuperSubMenu(){
            $(SuperSubMenuName).css({top: TopPosition, left: LeftPosition, position: "absolute"});
            $(SuperSubMenuName).css("display", "table-cell");
            $(SuperSubMenuName).children("li").each(function () {
                $(this).css("display", "inline-block");
            });
        }

        function HideSuperSubMenu() {
            $(SuperSubMenuName).css("display", "none");
            $(SuperSubMenuName).children("li").each(function () {
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            });
        }

        function HideSuperSubMenuIfNotViewing() {
            if (ViewingSuperSubMenu == false)
                HideSuperSubMenu();
        }

        function getPosition(element) {
            var xPosition = 0;
            var yPosition = 0;

            while (element) {
                xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
                yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
                element = element.offsetParent;
            }
            return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
        }
```

Comment: Although it's hard to determine what the OP is exactly after, this seems a little extreme.

Comment: This is way extreme, albeit hard to see what OP wants.  Beyond that, I'd argue that it's not exactly best practice either.  There's absolutely no reason to use Javascript to handle something as simple as a navigation with a drop down menu.  This is exactly what :hover is created and used for.

Comment: If you can reproduce this functionality with only CSS, please post code.

Comment: @Stan search the web for CSS dropdown/flyout menu, nothing new.